# How to change my dataset from linked list to edge list for social network analysis in R studio

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I currently have collaborative network data for technology development.
This data is stored as a csv file and consists of the following formats: It consists of more than 10,000 rows in total.

```
**[linked list data set]**
A(company) B(company) C(company)
B(company) C(company)
A(company) B(company) D(company)
```

```
**[edge list data set]**
A B 2
A C 1
B C 1
A D 1
```

I would like to convert this form of data into an edge list format to conduct network analysis in Rstudio.
However, I don't know how to convert these data.
NO idea how to do this. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, please provide the output from `dput(head(xxx))` (where `xxx` is the name of your linked list) in your question.  And, for those of us less familiar with your field than you are, please define how the values in your desired output are calculated.  It looks as if for each pair of objects (A, B C etc), you want the number of times the objects appear in the same element of the input list?

Comment: Is your edge list complete? What's the meaning of numerical values in your edge list? How is the edge list mapped from your first dataset? Better to give some explanation.